# In Dark Souls, do you need a slashing weapon to cut off Seath's tail?

Tags: dark-souls

I read on the [Wikidot Dark Souls](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/) wiki that you can [cut off Seath's tail](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/seath-the-scaleless#toc11) by inflicting it damage equivalent to [about 15% of his health](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/seath-the-scaleless#toc13).

Also, if I recall correctly, I managed to cut a gargoyle's tail using by big bad Great Club.

However, using the tactic described on the same page (have Seath blow on the great shard and use the stun time to slash his tail), I have managed to inflict very heavy damage to his tail (about a third of Seath's total health), and yet it did not cut off.

Is it possible at all to cut his tail with a non-slashing weapon?

Comment: Seath actually has a few tails (or at least a few things which resemble tails), but there is a specific one (the one in the back) you need to cut off. It's possible you're trying to cut off the wrong one.

Comment: @Wipqozn, I am indeed trying to cut the one in the back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you can cut off the tail with any weapon; however, you need to hit the tip of it, where there is no crystal.

Answer (score 1):

There is no weapon requirement to cut off his tail, however some weapons make the task easier.

For instance, I used a  weapon with decent range and a vertical slash, the Drake Sword. I didn't use a bigger weapon because being able to move fast is also important since you only have a few seconds to run to his tail and swipe it.

Also, try to  make sure you are hitting the very tip of his tail, it seems to help.

But most importantly, don't give up. It took me around 5 or 6 tries until I finally nailed it. Just keep hacking away at the tail, it can take some time.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know any weapon can be used to cut off the dragons' tails; you can use a bow to obtain the Drake Sword, for instance.  It's most likely that you're attacking the tail at the wrong point; you have to strike quite close to the tip for it to work.  Watch this video to see how they obtain it:

Hope that helps!

EDIT: Something to note is that you do not acquire the sword immediately after cutting the tail off. It will be obvious when the tail is cut off, but you won't actually get the sword until you examine the base of the cut-off tail section and pick it up.